# Choosing the most important variables in GLMs

Tags: generalized-linear-model, feature-selection, biostatistics

I am struggling with this problem, can anyone tell me how can I choose the most important variables among several independent variables before fitting any models in GLMs? I really appreciate it. I have already fitted some models but it doesn't make sense for me. Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to the site, @Alan. Your question is a little sparse to be answerable. Would you mind telling us more about your situation, your data, & your goals? Since you're new here, it would help you to read our [about page](http://stats.stackexchange.com/about) & our [FAQ](http://stats.stackexchange.com/faq), which contain info about the site & how to ask questions. You might also find this blog post helpful in formulating your question: [how to ask a statistics question](http://www.statisticalanalysisconsulting.com/how-to-ask-a-statistics-question/).

Comment: In general, choosing important variables with which to fit a model is done by thinking about the nature of the situation & what prior theory dictates is relevant.

Comment: Well, first thanks for replying, I have more than 20 independent variables, I need to find the model which fits the data well. So, in  this case, I want to find a way which variable has the most effect on the response variable in order to put into the model. Is it helpful??

Comment: For the most part, that is an extremely difficult problem. You may want to read my answer here: [algorithms-for-automatic-model-selection](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/20836//20856#20856).

Comment: Hi Alan. As @gung said, this is a hard problem. In your reply to him, you say you "need a model which fits the data well" that is not the same as finding the most important variables.
<br>
In many fields of research, many models will fit the data well and it can be very hard (if possible) to say which fits it **best**. Getting a better answer than that would depend on your needs; see gung 's first comment and tell us a lot more and then we can help more.

Comment: I understand what both of you commented, but the point is I have to put one of them into the model right? For example, for a particular disease if my independent variables are (Age,Gender,Smoke, Exercise and so on. I was asked to fit the models like this(model1<- glm(diseas ~1, family=poisson)) and the second model is( model2<- glm(diseas ~ Age,family=poisson)) as you we need to compare these two and decide whether Age is significant or not. My problem is when I accept the second model and after taking forward selection, I may end up with the best one, but if I put Gender first time,

Comment: The model would be another one. The whole thing is how do I know which one must be put into the model as a first variable?? I hope you can understand me.